# Awk (mawk) floors decimal numbers to zero

Tags: command-line, awk

It seems to me like a bug in `awk` (`mawk` 1.3.4.20200120-2) on Ubuntu 20.04. I can display required number of decimals with `printf (%.*n*f)`, but the decimals are always rounded to zero, as if there was implicit "floor" involved:, as you can see in the following examples.

- Example 1:

  ```
  $ echo "2.3 4.99789" | awk '{printf "%.2f %.2f\n", $1, $2}'
  2,00 4,00
  ```
- Example 2:

  ```
  $ cat testf
  1.23
  3.65
  5.76

  $awk '{ SUM += $1} END { printf "%.2f\n",  SUM }' testf
  9,00
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This was not an issue with `awk` (though it manifested in `awk`, not e.g. in bash when using `bc`). It was a simple locale misconfig/setting.

Eastern-European locale uses `,` as the decimal separator instead of `.`. My locale was a mixture of US setting and SK settings.

Solution:

Check: `cat /etc/default/locale` or with `locale` command for `LC_NUMERIC`.

E.g.: `LC_NUMERIC="sk_SK.UTF-8"`

Modify:

- either locally in `.bashrc`.
- or system-wide with:

  ```
  sudo update-locale LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8
  ```

  which will correctly update `/etc/default/locale` for you.